# my design wont show properly. is there a way to fix it?

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I have designed my WordPress website using Elementor and Porto theme.
suddenly it doesn't work at all and wont show properly.it seems that, the CSS cant work.
here is a screenshot
[image: a screenshot of my website]

is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try heading into Wordpress dashboard, elementor, tools - and then hit that 'regenerate files and data' button. Sometimes this fixes EVERYTHING! Best of luck.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).